# sshpass in .ssh/config?

Tags: ssh, sshpass

When running the command:

```
ssh minix.p
```

what I really want run is:

```
sshpass -f ~/.ssh/minix-password ssh minix.p
```

Is there any way I can do that?

**Background**

I want to use `sshfs` and similar tools, so I cannot just make a script called `sshminix` - it really has to literally be the exact letters `ssh minix.p` that executes the above. On top of that the minix installation I have access to only supports password authentication, so I cannot used normal ssh public keys or `ssh-agent`.

Comment: Why not just use an alias?

Comment: @NasirRiley How? `ssh not-minix` should still run `ssh not-minix`.

Comment: Why not us a ssh key?

Comment: You said that you want to run `sshpass -f ~/.ssh/minix-password ssh minix.p`. Why not just create an alias that runs that command?

Comment: @RalfFriedl As written: "the minix installation I have access to only supports password authentication".

Comment: @NasirRiley The programs I use will call `ssh <hostname>`, so I need the syntax to be `ssh minix` and not some other command. This is also the reason I do not just simply make a script called 'sshminix' or some other name.

Comment: You can still use an alias: `mssh = "sshpass -f ~/.ssh/minix-password ssh minix.p"`. You can make one for each host you want to connect to via `ssh`. If the host is called "gummibear" then you can use an alias: `gssh = "sshpass -f ~/.ssh/gummibear-password ssh gummibear.p"`.

Comment: @NasirRiley The problem is that *I* do not call `ssh minix`. It is another tool that call that (Think tools like `sshfs`). And I cannot change the tool to run `gssh` instead, because it uses `ssh <hostname>` with different hostnames. Show me how your solution will work with `sshfs`.

Comment: Then you need to clarify what you are doing in your question. With the way it's written, it looks like you are only running a command. Include what you are doing in its entirety including the program that is running.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot provide a password in the SSH configuration, but you could run `sshfs -o ssh_command=minixsshwrapper` with `minixsshwrapper` being a script like:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec sshpass -f ~/.ssh/minix-password ssh "$@"
```

If changing the sshfs arguments is not possible then you could create the wrapper script as `ssh` in a directory to be added in fron of `$PATH`.